# In-App Purchase with Commercial app at same time?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have an app in Apple store. It is commercial with 1 USD. Is it possible to add InApp Purchase features in this app at same time ? 
Thank you

Comment: Are you asking if a non-free app can also have in-app purchases? Yes. Why not?

Comment: Hi @rmaddy Yes. is it possible or Apple limited me ?